# pip wont work on this particular computer

Tags: python, pip

how can i make pip work.

ive been trying to get pip to work for a long time on this particular laptop. ive had it working on a bunch of others. but never this laptop for some reason.

in an attempt to get pip to work i deleted everything python on this laptop and started fresh (deleted python 3.6, 3.7, anaconda and all of my environment variables) and reinstalled 3.7 telling the python installer to install pip for me. 
it added the environment variables itself but pip still wont work.

[a screenshot showing the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge8GG.png)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `pip install pygame`, try to use `python -m pip install pygame`, it should work.